# Using case statement to remove ISNULL's in my SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
declare @sSQL VARCHAR(2000)

SET sSQL='Select top 20 ID 
FROM Prospects 
WHERE p.StatusID not in (-1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14)'
+CASE WHEN @state IS NULL THEN '' ELSE CHAR(10) + 'AND P.State = '+ CHAR(39)+@State +CHAR(39) end
```

The above piece does not return any state value and I want to maintain the ISNULL functionality.
The original one was having the where clause like this -- 'p.State = IsNull(@State, p.State)'

Comment: That's Microsoft SQL Server syntax. Why did you tag this question [tag:mysql]?

Comment: coalesce is more universal than isnull what about `p.State = coalesce(@state, p.state)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to add query in varchar variable. You can achieve it without using any variable like this -

**Solution-1:**

```
SELECT TOP 20 ID
FROM Prospects
WHERE p.StatusID NOT IN (-1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14)
    AND (
        P.STATE = @State
        OR @State IS NULL
        )
```

**Solution-2:**

```
SELECT TOP 20 ID
FROM Prospects
WHERE p.StatusID NOT IN (-1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14)
    AND P.STATE = COALESCE(@State, P.STATE)
```

**Solution-3:** Dynamic query (Which i always tried to avoid).

```
SET @sSQL = 'Select top 20 ID 
FROM Prospects 
WHERE p.StatusID not in (-1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14)' + (
        CASE 
            WHEN @state IS NULL
                THEN ''
            ELSE ' AND P.State = ' + QUOTENAME(@State, '''')
            END
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try leaving out the special characters and just using spaces instead and putting the value of `@State` in single quotes:

```
SET sSQL = 'Select top 20 ID 
FROM Prospects 
WHERE p.StatusID not in (-1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14)' +
(CASE WHEN @state IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' AND P.State = ''' + @State + '''' end)
```

Alternatively, you could write this as:

```
SET sSQL = 'Select top 20 ID 
FROM Prospects 
WHERE p.StatusID not in (-1,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,12,13,14)' +
(CASE WHEN @state IS NULL THEN '' ELSE ' AND P.State = @State' end)
```

And execute the statement using `sp_executesql` rather than just `exec`.